# Find PDF of minimum of 4 independent functions

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$,and$ X_4$ be four mutually independent random variables, each with p.d.f. $f(x) = 3(1-x)^2$, $x \in (0, 1)$, and zero elsewhere. If Y is the minimum of these four variables, find the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of Y.

What I have so far: 
$Y=X_1$ iff $X_1 \lt X_2,X_3,X_4 $ so the pdf should include $(f(x))^3$ somewhere... just not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Note that $P(Y\le c)=1-P(Y>c)$ and
$$
P(Y>c) = P(X_1\ge c, X_2\ge c, X_3\ge c, X_4 \ge c),
$$
and use their independence property.

Comment: What is c here?

Comment: $c$ can be any value. To find the CDF you need to find $F_Y(c)=P(Y\le c)$ for all $c\in \mathbb R$ (real numbers).

Answer (score 1):

$$F_{min}(x) = P(X_{min} \leq x)$$ $$= 1- P(X_{min} > x)$$$$= 1-P(X_1 > x; X_2 > x;\cdots X_4 > x)$$
$$= 1 - [1 - F_1(x)][1 - F_2(x)]\cdots[1 - F_4(x)]$$
For x > 0,$$ F_{i}(x)  =\int_{0}^{x}3(1-x^2)dx$$